# Avoiding Losing my Shell with set -e

Tags: bash, shell-script

I'd like to use set -e in a bash script, but every time I run it any error kills my shell.

```
  say I have script.sh:

  #! /usr/bin/env bash
  set -e
  my_commmand
  my_other_command
```

An error in `my_command` blows up my shell whether I do:

```
 % ./script.sh (after chmod)
```

or

```
 % . ./script.sh
```

There must be an easy way around this.

Comment: Using `set -e` inside a script is not supposed to terminate your shell if you invoke it as `./script.sh`. Are you sure that's actually happening as you describe? Can you try to build a small reproducible example that demonstrates it? Are you sure you don't already have `set -e` on your shell? (You can disable it with `set +e` and you can see which options are set with `echo $-`). Good luck!

Comment: Patient: "Doctor, it hurts when I do (this)"; Doctor: "Well, stop doing (that)" -- are you sure you really need/want to use `set -e`

Answer (score 4):

Do you mean that your interactive shell exits?

If you source a script (with `.`) that sets `set -e` from your interactive shell, the "exit-on-error" flag will also be set in your interactive shell. If you've done that before, then it will apply to any command you run afterwards, be it a sourced script (`. ./script.sh`), or one started normally (`./script.sh`).

The solution is to not source scripts that `set -e`.

You may also want to see [BashFAQ 105](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/105) on other issues with `set -e`.

Comment: That's why I thought executing it would not kill the shell, but that kills the shell too.

Comment: @RaySalemi, what I mean is that if you run `. ./script.sh`, and it succeeds, then `set -e` will be in effect in your interactive shell. Afterwards, running `./script.sh` would trigger the error exit if the script now failed. Either it's that, or you have `set -e` in some of the shell's startup files. But just running that script normally, will not exit the main interactive shell.

Comment: But should ./script.sh kill the shell?  I thought it should not

Comment: @RaySalemi It will not. But, if you have previously run `. ./script.sh` this would enable `set -e` in the interactive shell.  A failure in `script.sh` when running it as `./script.sh` would then kill the interactive shell.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to have `set -e` in an interactive shell, and want to execute a command which may return nonzero, you need to catch that exit code.  One method:

```
$ some_command || :
```

Another:

```
$ if ! some_command; then :; fi
```

Answer (score 0):

If you did ever call `set -e` in your login shell and then run a command that returns a non-zero exit code that is not used in a compound statement, then your login shell will exit:

```
set -e
false
```

will log you out.

If you did ever run a script that includes `set -e` using `. ./script` you did set `-e` in your login shell.

If you later run any command with non zero exit code: bingo.